# Get the Recent changed value from History Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a history table with the following values

```
CREATE TABLE History (SnapShotDate DATETIME, UID VARCHAR(10), DUEDATE DATETIME)

INSERT INTO History VALUES ('03-23-2015','PT-01','2015-04-22')
INSERT INTO History VALUES  ('03-30-2015','PT-01','2015-04-20')
INSERT INTO History VALUES  ('04-06-2015','PT-01','2015-06-30')

INSERT INTO History VALUES  ('03-23-2015','PT-02','2015-04-22')
INSERT INTO History VALUES  ('03-30-2015','PT-02','2015-04-22')
INSERT INTO History VALUES  ('04-06-2015','PT-02','2015-04-22')

INSERT INTO History VALUES  ('03-23-2015','PT-03','2015-04-18')
INSERT INTO History VALUES  ('03-30-2015','PT-03','2015-04-22')
INSERT INTO History VALUES  ('04-06-2015','PT-03','2015-04-22')
```

I need an output in the below format. I need the most recent changed value for any given UID. Please help me in getting the below result

OUTPUT

```
 UID    PreviousDueDate  CurrentDueDate
----------------------------------------
 PT-01     2015-04-20      2015-06-30
 PT-02     2015-04-22      2015-04-22
 PT-03     2015-04-18      2015-04-22
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have date columns' datatype as varchar (as mentioned in one of your comments), why did you put datetime in the create table statement? It's not helpful for people trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this SQL:

```
select UID,date_format(min(DUEDATE), '%Y-%m-%d') as PreviousDueDate,date_format(max(DUEDATE), '%Y-%m-%d') as CurrentDueDate from History group by UID;
```

Comment: I get this error when running the query you gave  Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 34
'date_format' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: date_format is a MySQL function to format date. If you are not using MySQL, then you can omit that format part

Comment: I need q query which gives data by checking against SnapshotDate. Sometimes CurrentDue Date value can be a smaller value than the previous due date`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UID, 
(SELECT DUEDATE FROM  History WHERE SnapShotDate=(SELECT MIN(SnapShotDate) FROM  History h2 WHERE h2.UID=h1.UID) )AS PreviousDueDate
(SELECT DUEDATE FROM  History WHERE SnapShotDate=(SELECT MAX(SnapShotDate) FROM  History WHERE h2.UID=h1.UID) )AS CurrentDueDate
FROM History h1
GROUP BY UID
```

Comment: Hmm This will not work when the record is something like this


INSERT
 
 
 
INTOHistory VALUES  ('03-23-2015','PT-04','2015-04-20')

 
INSERT
 
 
 
INTOHistory VALUES  ('03-30-2015','PT-04','2015-04-22')

 
INSERT
 
 
 
INTOHistory VALUES  ('04-06-2015','PT-04','2015-04-18')
 
I need a query which uses the History Date and picks the last modified one. I need to apply this logic for a similar requirement which has a text column instead of duedate

Comment: when you group by UID in Subquery it returns more than one value and gives me this error       - Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
. Please provide me a query where I can use this logic for text columns unlike Duedate as well.

Comment: you can use a WHERE clause instead of group by

Answer (score 0):

You should use Convert function in sql server.

```
SELECT A.UID
,CONVERT(varchar(10),B.DUEDATE, 20) as PreviousDueDate
,CONVERT(varchar(10),A.DUEDATE, 20) as CurrentDueDate
FROM
(
    SELECT *,row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY SnapShotDate DESC) AS ROWID
    FROM History
)A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT *,row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY SnapShotDate DESC) AS ROWID
    FROM History
)B ON A.UID=B.UID AND B.ROWID=2
WHERE A.ROWID=1
GROUP BY A.UID,A.DUEDATE,B.DUEDATE
```

Output：

```
UID     PreviousDueDate CurrentDueDate
PT-01   2015-04-20      2015-06-30
PT-02   2015-04-22      2015-04-22
PT-03   2015-04-22      2015-04-22
PT-04   2015-04-22      2015-04-18
```

Comment: This will not work when the last changed Due Date is less than the previous Due date? Can you please provide me a query which used Snapshot Date and checks for the most recent changed value. I need this query to apply on text column as well like I am doing for Due date right now

Comment: The PreviousDueDate of PT-03 should be "2015-04-22" not "2015-04-18".

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the LAG function before so but seems super easy!!!

```
; WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT UID, 
    LAG(DUEDATE,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY SnapShotDate ASC) AS PreviousDueDate,
    DUEDATE AS CurrentDueDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY SnapShotDate DESC) AS RowNumber
  FROM History
)
SELECT UID, PreviousDueDate, CurrentDueDate
FROM CTE
WHERE ROWNUMBER = 1
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1ed8/11).

Comment: For the PT-03 record , the previous Due Date should be 2015-04-18 which I do not get using your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UID, 
(SELECT MIN(DUEDATE) FROM  History HS WHERE  HS.UID =  H.UID  GROUP BY  UID )AS PreviousDueDate,
(SELECT Max(DUEDATE) FROM  History HS WHERE  HS.UID =  H.UID GROUP BY  UID )AS CurrentDueDate
FROM History  H
GROUP BY UID
```